# Autenticação única para multiplos projetos utilizando Entity Framework

Tags: asp.net-mvc, entity-framework, login, forms-authentication

Atualmente em minha solution possuo vários projetos ASP.NET web, cada um com o código padrão de autenticação default do entity framework MVC (existem pequenas customizações nas entidades somente). Os projetos compartilham as mesmas entidades e o mesmo banco de dados.

O problema está quando eu quero acessar dois projetos ao mesmo tempo. Por exemplo, quando acesso o projeto "Financeiro", o projeto "Vendas" que já estava logado, desloga.

Como faço para manter os dois projetos logados ao mesmo tempo com o mesmo usuário?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

primeiro passo é ter um `cookie` único para todos o projetos, para tal, edite o seu `web.config` e atribua o mesmo nome para o Cookie de Autenticação.

```
<authentication mode="Forms">
  <forms name=".MY_AUTH_COOKIE_NAME" protection="All" cookieless="AutoDetect" enableCrossAppRedirects="true" path="/" />
</authentication>
```

Mas levando em consideração que o sistema já está deslogando dos demais sistemas ao logar em um sistema, acredito que todas as aplicações estão à compartilhar o mesmo cookie, então você pode pular esta etapa.

O segundo ponto, é garantir que todas as aplicações tenham o mesmo `machinekey`, novamente você terá de configurar isto no `web.config`:

```
<machineKey
  validationKey="336C0D608AF11D8B6613F6D235C980885F74B284254A034FA33E59E39FAB7987BD97F3DE9DEA14A1B625966642CBAC92A46DDB5EBF5CDDB44C7DB0F1CB4D5887"
  decryptionKey="A71C792B7E90217ECBCFCCE25E24466B2E52C3ED686513C2FA2418639624626F"
  validation="SHA1" decryption="AES"
/>
```

Você pode consultar o seguinte artigo para saber como gerar o machineKey.: [Easiest way to generate MachineKey](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/amb/2012/07/31/easiest-way-to-generate-machinekey/)

Caso esteja usando `ASP.NET Identity` com `Entity Framework` e colocou a `tag` "forms-authentication" de forma erronia, então leia o seguinte artigo.: [Sharing authentication cookies between applications](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/security/data-protection/compatibility/cookie-sharing)